# mysqld: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused

Tags: mysql, docker, monitoring, prometheus

I'm trying to dockerize monitoring of `mysql` using `prom/mysqld-exporter` and `prom/prometheus`. I have configured the **docker-compose.yml** file like the following:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql

    # command: 
    #   - CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 3;
    #   - GRANT PROCESS, REPLICATION CLIENT, SELECT ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE= db #Defining a new Database
      - MYSQL_USER= mostafa
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD= ghadimi
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
      - 33060:33060

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - prometheus:/prometheus
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    command: 
      - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml

  mysql-exporter:
    image: prom/mysqld-exporter
    container_name: mysql-exporter
    ports:
      - 9104:9104
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-exporter/.my.cnf:/root/.my.cnf
    depends_on: 
      - mysql

volumes:
  mysql:
  prometheus:
```

and here is my ./mysql-exporter/.my.cnf file:

```
[client]
user=mostafa
password=ghadimi
```

After running `docker-compose up` command, everything works properly except the following error!:

mysqld: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused

I don't know how can I fix it!

**PS:** I have also tried to connect to mysql through its container and `docker exec -it <container-id> bash` command and I have attempted all the possible passwords (like empty string and the password I have set in docker-compose file), but I face with another error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: which container raises this error?

Comment: @michalk `prom/mysqld-exporter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql-d exporter is looking for mysql instance on `localhost`, but it is not running on the `localhost` inside mysqld container. You will have to pass external connection string with the host of `mysql` because this is the name of mysql service in docker-compose. From [`mysqld-exporter docs`](https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/mysqld-exporter/) - you will have to pass environment variable to mysqld-exporter container with this datasource connection string :

```
mysql-exporter:
    image: prom/mysqld-exporter
    container_name: mysql-exporter
    ports:
      - 9104:9104
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-exporter/.my.cnf:/root/.my.cnf
    environment:
      - DATA_SOURCE_NAME="user:password@mysql:3306/database"
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
```

And change user, password and database name to your desired ones.